# Rsyslog: imfile does not switch to inotify mode

Tags: nginx, rsyslog, loggly

I'm trying to send multiple nginx logs to loggly...
Config file: /etc/rsyslog.d/21-nginx.conf

```
$ModLoad imfile
    #$InputFilePollInterval 10
    $InputFileMode inotify
    $WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
    $PrivDropToGroup adm

    # nginx access file:
    $InputFileName /var/log/nginx/*access.log
    $InputFileTag nginx-access:
    $InputFileStateFile stat-nginx-access
    $InputFileSeverity info
    $InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
    $InputRunFileMonitor

    # other stuff continues......
```

after restart i get this error in log syslog:

```
imfile: The to-be-monitored file "/var/log/nginx/*access.log" contains wildcards. This is not supported in polling mode. [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2420 ]
activation of module imfile failed [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/-3 ]
```

did i make something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are there other places in your rsyslog configuration where the file mode is changed to pulling or the file poll interval is active? The problem with using this kind of legacy syntax is that all the configuration is loaded globally, so things in other configuration files can interact. You might consider using the new action syntax so that the inotify mode is applied to the specific source. You can see an example of it here http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html